Why does storage layer encode length rather than offset when store batches for the string/binary type? E.g. parquet, clickhouse columar format
I find many olap databases or storage specs uses length rather than offset to store variable-length type. But why?
I found storing length always get much better compression ratio than offset. But can anyone explain the reason. Does it relate to some kind of compression algorithm? Or all compression algorithms?
E.g. parquet format


please be more specific where length and offset are used, it depends on the case might matter or not.

When we try to store string type field in some file format on disk, we need to store all the raw data as a byte array and a index (marking the start and the end offset of each row). For the index part, we can either store the offset or the length of each row. But it seems most storage spec choose to store the length. I also added a picture to illustrate my question.

For the picture content you mentioned, it should use length to represent the size of the array, 32 bits should be enough. I don't see anything related to compression here.

We can use the offset to calculate the size of the array. So can use store the offset of each array's first byte rather than the length of each array?
